# Async XML Reading Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm currently reading xml files with XDocument.
The XML is being read in a method with parameters, which looks currently like this:

```
private MyXmlFiles_Row GetXmlData(int Year, TAN ANAG, TVerdTyp VerdTyp) {

    XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("XML\\MyXmlFiles.xml");
    XName SucheName = "MyXmlFiles";
        IEnumerable<MyXmlFiles_Row> filteredData = from query in loadedCustomData.Descendants(SucheName)
        where query.Element("Year").Value == Year.ToString().Trim() && query.Element("TAN").Value == ANAG.ToString().Trim() && query.Element("TVerdTyp").Value == VerdTyp.ToString().Trim()
        select new BeitrProzent_Row(    
                    Convert.ToDouble(query.Element("One").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Convert.ToDouble(query.Element("Two").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Convert.ToDouble(query.Element("Three").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Convert.ToDouble(query.Element("Four").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Convert.ToDouble(query.Element("Five").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    return filteredData.ElementAt(0);
}
```

How can I load the xml files async (or with a BackgroundWorker)?

Comment: It seems you would need to read the contents of the file into a `string` asynchronously and then use `XDocument.Parse()`.

Comment: Return `Task<MyXmlFiles_Row>` and `async` that puppy.  Also, please save poor C# developer's eyes and remove that underscore from your type name.  Ugh.  What do you think this is?  [tag:PHP]?

Comment: Thanks. I've also already tried to use Task, but I have to rewrite a lot of code :/
Btw. it's a given program. I don't use underscores in type names (or at all) either :P

Comment: @Rudi, why do you think you'll have to rewrite more code using tasks than with any other asynchronous technology?
Wither way, ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is still your friend. But I would go with a task.

Comment: I didn't say that it's more code than other async technology. I meant that I have to rewrite several methods, because I'm calling the method above in another method, and this method again in another method, and...